# sql limit join with a scope

Tags: sql, db2

I have following sql. This one works fine but takes a lot of time due to the fact that the files ar and py both contain a huge number of records. Is there a way to limit the join to the documents from the in part of the sql ? So only join the articlenumber (ararnr) 1002032 , 1904140 etc...

```
SELECT ararnr,ararir,pyarnr,pypykd,pyarpy
FROM ar left join
     py
     on ar.ararnr = py.pyarnr and pypykd ='C' and
        ararnr in '1002032','1904140', etc..
ORDER BY case when ararnr='1002032' then 1 ararnr ='1904140' then 2 etc... end";
```

By the way I'm using DB2 for I series sql

Comment: Edit your question and provide qualified column names so readers know where the columns are coming from.

Comment: create the non-clustered indexe on the columns you are using in ON condition and include the select list columns in INCLUDED of the nonclustered index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't make sense, because you have a `left join` with conditions on the *first* table in the `on` clause. I assume you intend:

```
SELECT ararnr, ararir, pyarnr, pypykd, pyarpy
FROM ar left join
     py
     on ar.ararnr = py.pyarnr and py.pypykd ='C' 
WHERE ar.ararnr in ('1002032', '1904140', . . .)
ORDER BY case when ararnr='1002032' then 1 ararnr ='1904140' then 2 etc... end";
```

For this query, you want indexes on `ar(ararnr)` and `py(ararnr, pypkd)`.  That might improve performance.